# Reminders doesn't work (Google Keep, Any.Do, ...)

Tags: notifications, alarm, alerts, google-keep

No reminders work in applications like Google Keep or Any.Do

But when standard alarm event is fired - boom! All past reminders that you were supposed to remember 5 hours ago are displayed.

How to make them work as they should?

No greenify or similar app is installed. The phone is Alcatel One Touch with Android 4.3.